# Bluetooth headphones initialize with Audio Profile = Off upon connection, possibly because of "Profile a2dp_sink has no transport" problem

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

This is a fully updated Ubuntu 18.04 with `blueman`. Whenever I connect a paired headset, the connection goes through reliably, except the `Audio Profile` is initialized to `Off`. Which means no sound is outputted by the headphones, until I manually set the `Audio Profile` to `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` in the `blueman-manager` gui, after which the headphones work perfectly.

Is there a way to automatically switch `Audio Profile` to `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` upon connection?

I suspect this might be the default mode of operation, and its failure may have to do with the following warning `pulseaudio` outputs when I connect the headphone:

`W: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: Profile a2dp_sink has no transport`

Just as a reminder: when I manually switch after I connect and see this warning, sound output works perfectly and I no longer see any warnings.

I can also set audio profile from the command line:

`pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink`

This achieves the same result as switching the profile from the `blueman-manager` gui: the headphones then work well.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm struggling with the same.

Comment: @rogerkk Unfortunately I never found a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be one of the numerous errors that are never fixed (keeping all non nerd users from using Ubuntu)

I wrote a little script for that and created a desktop symbol for it, so I don't need to fiddle with the bluetooth settings ten times a day.
This only works if you have exactly one device attached.

```
# Find the index no. of the bluetooth device
bt_dev_index=`pacmd list-cards | grep bluez_card -B1 | grep index | awk '{print $2}'`
echo -e index = $bt_dev_index\\n
# Set desired bluetooth audio profile for the found index.
pacmd set-card-profile $bt_dev_index a2dp_sink
```

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts as well. Based on this question and answer, I did the following:

First I used `pacmd list-cards` to find the name of the bluez_card. The relevant output was:

```
index: 16
    name: <bluez_card.00_1B_66_B4_4A_D4>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 43
    properties:
        device.description = "PXC 550-II"
```

Then I created a keyboard shortcut for this command:

`pacmd set-card-profile 'bluez_card.00_1B_66_B4_4A_D4' a2dp_sink`

Now, when I connect my headphones, I can just hit the keyboard shortcut and they work.