# Set Build in audio Profile to Analog Stereo Output in Pulse Audio Volume Control

Tags: sound, scripts, pulseaudio

Hello i recently installed  Ubuntu 20.04.. After installing i found that there is no volume in  front headphone . Then i found that if i change "Set Build in audio Profile" to "Analog Stereo Output in  Pulse Audio Volume Control" Sound Comes back the problem is i need to set it to analog every time i log in so i was wondering **if there is a way to make Build in audio Profile to analog every time i log in . like adding one line of code in .bashrc ??** that's all thank you [This is the image showing what to change into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdruA.png)

Comment: There is a command line tool `pacmd` that could allow automating this change during login. See for inspiration here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120433/bluetooth-headphones-initialize-with-audio-profile-off-upon-connection-possib

Comment: i am relatively new to using Ubuntu . and unable to understand then contents of above link

Comment: I also would need to find out how it works, otherwise I would have posted as an answer. It can help you nevertheless in your search, or inspire someone else who may be able to help here.